# Module '"../../parse5/lib"' has no exported member 'ElementLocation' - Angular Universal Firebase deployment error

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, deployment

i have a problem with deployment of angular universal on firebase hosting. I am following deployment on circleci and i am getting this error below in their console. Is that related to node version or what?

I dont know where to start finding the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Quick-fixed it by updating the `parse5` package, thanks to [this](https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/370#issuecomment-601787438).

```bash
npm install parse5@latest
```

Comment: to me neither, same issue

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for me in this issue report https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26338

I have to install `npm i --save-dev @types/jsdom@11.0.4`

It's weird, because I've never had a error like that

Comment: For me it was there but needed to be updated to a version that matches the version of `jsdom`, the types package was older somehow

Comment: This no longer works as a solution.